# Monotuch : RadioGroup selected event

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xampp

How can i handle choised radio in radio Group??

```
var root = new RootElement ("Meals") {
    new Section ("Dinner"){
            new RootElement ("Dessert", new RadioGroup ("dessert", 2)) {
                new Section () {
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "dessert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Milkshake", "dessert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Chocolate Cake", "dessert")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Tapped" Event of the RadioElement Class.